how to exclude package.json file for built app's asar, when it is built with nextron and electron builder, electron
tutors!
i would like to exclude package.json from my electron app but the electron builder options is not working
electron-builder.yml

files:
  - from: .
    filter:
      - app
      - "!package.json" 
  
  - from: resources
    to: resources
    filter:
      - "**/*"

i have tried glob as well, but no luck
how can i exclude package.json from my app.asar package of electron(nextron) ?

i have tried glob path, tried to directly remove it after built app
but it was not working
